# Does Google AppEngine PYTHON flexible Environment support task queues?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I have been long using GAE STANDARD with webApp2. It has great support and documentation for task queues. But now I just started using Python FLASK with Google AppEngine FLEXIBLE, I could not find any clear documentation for task queues, as compared to the documentation and support for Task Queues in GAE Standard.
If task queues are supported, or any one has used them please share the links or documentation which may be helpful.
Secondly if any alternative or better way for background tasks i.e Celery etc in your opinion?
Any opinions would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#task_queues) in [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating):

> The Task Queue service has limited availability outside of the
>   standard environment. If you want to use the service outside of the
>   standard environment, you can sign up for the [Cloud Tasks alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true).
>
> Outside of the standard environment, you can't add tasks to [push
>   queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/#push_queues), but a service running in the flexible environment can be
>   the target of a push task. You can specify this using the
>   [`target`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) parameter when adding a task to queue or by specifying
>   the default `target` for the queue in [`queue.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref).
>
> In many cases where you might use pull queues, such as queuing up
>   tasks or messages that will be pulled and processed by separate
>   workers, [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) can be a good alternative as it offers
>   similar functionality and delivery guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

As Dan answered that Cloud Pub/Sub is a good alternative.
here is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070442/monitoring-the-status-of-a-google-pub-sub-submitted-job/37165907) that I found, which is quiet helpful.